# evince seems to ignore $DISPLAY on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, evince

I am running Fedora 33:

```
Linux mainoumi 5.14.18-100.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 12 17:38:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a PC running Xming (X11 server)  7.7.0.85 and PuTTy .78 (both pretty recent).

My Linux box's .cshrc sets my DISPLAY to point to my PC's Xserver, `192.168.11.17:0.0` .

When I launch `xeyes` or `emacs`, the window appears correctly on my PC, but when I start evince, it displays on the Linux laptop for some reason.  `ldd /usr/bin/evince` shows it's based on X11 libraries.

I ran `strace /usr/bin/evince Hello.pdf >& evince.strace`

and I see the following text:

```
connect(11, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.11.17")}, 16) = 0
```

The X-server's port number is indeed 6000, and the address is correct, so it seems to be trying to connect correctly!

Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `GDK_BACKEND=x11` to force it to use x11 rather than Wayland.

Wayland is the defacto successor to X11, but uses a very different architecture. You can read about that here: [Wayland, Chapter 3. Wayland Architecture: X vs. Wayland Architecture](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch03.html#sect-Wayland-Architecture-wayland_architecture). Crucially for our purposes, Wayland has no equivalent to X11's network redirection, and the `DISPLAY` variable isn't meaningful.

Wayland offers support for X11 applications that don't understand Wayland natively (documented at [Wayland, Chapter 5. X11 Application Support](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/ch05.html)). But, many apps — including modern ones using the GTK toolkit — are built with native Wayland support, and usually with that as the "first priority" when Wayland is available.

So, when these apps start, and find Wayland, they just run. Wayland doesn't care about `DISPLAY`, and... there you go.

But, if the application toolkit also has x11 support, you can tell it to use that instead — that's what `GDK_BACKEND=x11` is doing for GTK apps. For Qt apps (as in KDE), `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` is the equivalent.

Comment: Many thanks.  I know X11 inside out from the 90s but actually find the lack of  documentation on my Fedora system frustrating: the GUI system gives no clue what it's even called so I can't google it, the evince page has no mention of its display tech, etc.  I've slowly figured out that Wayland is a thing but why would an app default to use direct communication with Wayland if a perfectly good DISPLAY is set?  And in fact my strace shows it IS actually opening my Xserver?

Comment: Updated my answer — hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Qt tip too.